Blazor using global:: even if referenced in _Imports.razor
In my Blazor client app i do not understand why there is a global:: prefix in my references DLL.
_Imports.razor:
@using MyDll.Namespace

MyRazorComponent.razor:
@using global::MyDll.Namespace

Expected behavior in MyRazorComponent.razor:
@using MyDll.Namespace

What am i missing?

A folder with the same name caused a namespace conflict.
That's why global:: was added.
After resolving the namespace conflict (renaming the folder to something different) i could reference the DLL as usual.

